# selection bugs in viewport

Tags: mesh, 3d-view, selection-tools, error

Not sure if this is a 3.0 bug or an error created by settings carried over from previous versions but I'm coming across weird selection behavior in the viewport. sometimes when I create a new object I can't select the mesh in object mode unless I select it through the outliner, and yes the "disable selection" button is not active in outliner.

I also found out that if I create new faces on the mesh, I can select the object by clicking the new faces but not by clicking the original mesh, so it definitely seems more like its a program error rather than some mystery variable in my settings. Anybody else experiencing this issue?

Edit: the issue seems to happen most with planes, but if i extrude another plane from the plane i can select by clicking the new one in object mode but not by clicking the original.